# How to install ROS 1 in Ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to know which version and how can I install ROS 1 in Ubuntu 22.10?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/409357/how-to-install-ros-1-in-ubuntu-22.10?/) by [akumar3.1428](https://answers.ros.org/users/110426/akumar3.1428/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2022-11-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS 1, does not officially support Ubuntu 22.10. However, you can build ROS Noetic from source. Please read #q399664 for further details. It is related to Ubuntu 22.04 though but should work with 22.10

Please share errors if found during the compilation process.

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0